# CrashReporter itself keeps crashing

Tags: snow-leopard, crash

I never get crash logs when an application crashes, and the reason is that CrashReporter itself crashes:

```
4/20/12 10:11:25 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501[104]
(com.apple.ReportCrash.Self[133]) Job appears to have crashed: Trace/BPT trap
```

A google search shows that I'm not the only person to experience this. But I haven't found a definitive cure. A popular google hit suggests moving the LaunchAgents .plist file from the System LaunchAgents to the User LaunchAgents, but that made no difference for me. I'm wondering if anyone has actually solved this.

(This is on Snow Leopard. I have a Lion installation and another Snow Leopard computer; the problem doesn't occur there. It's just this one volume.)

Comment: Are you looking to learn how to narrow down a crash report or just move on?

Answer (score 1):

try these two things:

1. boot to safe mode, and then reboot. (hold Shift at system chime)
2. boot to single user mode, delete /Systems/Library/Caches & subdirectories

fixed lots of crash reporter errors on my machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you can reproduce this on a clean installation on that machine, it might be interesting to track down why and how the OS has become corrupted. It's not a tidy answer, but even for someone that can debug things - without the source code to the program this may be chasing a needle in a haystack to know why one of your computers isn't happy when it's crashing.